# using *ngIf to display a form

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

how can I fix this problem

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: __webpack_require__.e is not
a function message: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
__webpack_require__.e is not a function TypeError: __webpack_require__.e is not a function
```

Comment: no, it not due to *ngIf

Comment: I'm not sure how this problem is related to a form or `*ng-if`.  It's really unclear what your problem actually might be.

Comment: Please add the source code you think causing this error. This could be your package.json. tsconfig.json or webpack.json

Comment: A simple example for NgIf http://www.prashant-kumar.in/use-ngif-angular-js/ . it seems something related to webpack

Comment: I figure out what was wrong it was not the problem of `*ng-If `: it was to restart my server. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out what was wrong it was not the problem of `*ng-If` or form: the server needed to be restarted